# Универсальная компиляция

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте.

Имеется несколько серверов RHEL4, RHEL5, RHEL6. 
Сервера имеют архитектуру x86_64, так и i386.
Имеются исходники, которые компилируют бинарник просто

```
./configure && make
```

Можно ли скомпилировать что-то вроде универсального или максимально универсального бинарника? Чтобы не приходилось компилировать на каждом сервере? Спасибо

Comment: Теоретически -- иногда (зависит от кода) да, практически -- зависит слишком от многих факторов. Короче, на видя ./configure, кода и что установлено на серверах на Ваш вопрос не ответить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в общем, абстрактном, случае — ответ отрицательный.

но в частных случаях (зависящих от многих факторов) можно сократить количество сборок до двух (32/64 бита), и даже до одной, 32-битной.

проще всего выяснить, попадает ли данная программа в диапазон подобных частных случаев, — методом «научного тыка»: собрать и попробовать запустить на перечисленных машинах.

---

**иллюстрация для частного случая**. вот такая программа `hello.c`, будучи скомпилирована на 32-битной системе командой *make hello*, с огромной долей вероятности отлично заработает на подавляющем большинстве машин *intel-архитектуры* в среде операционной системы *gnu/linux*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```